# Unable to push data into an array when reading csv using createReadStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, node-csv-parse

I am trying to store data from a csv file in an array using createReadStream in node.js but for some reason the array stays empty and no data is stored in it.
When i console log the values where i'am trying to push the data it logs it just fine.
I've tried both csv-parser and csv-parse for this but none of them seem to work.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require('csv-parser');

function parseCSV () {
    let finaldata = []
    fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', function (row){
        finaldata.push({Userid: row[0], Timestamp: row[1]})
    }).on('end', function(){
        console.log(finaldata)
    })
}
parseCSV()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this using the following code below.
I kept experimenting to land on something that finally worked.
I have no idea why this fix works but i would love an explanation.

The change i made here is to call the Object constructor instead of using {} so `finaldata.push(Object(row))` instead of  `finaldata.push({Userid: row[0], Timestamp: row[1]})`

```
const fs = require("fs");
const csv = require('csv-parser');

const parseCSV = () => {
    let finaldata = []
    fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
        finaldata.push(Object(row))
    }).on('end', () => {
        console.log(finaldata)
    })
}
parseCSV()
```